# Will socket.io broadcast without listener consume resources?

Tags: node.js, sockets, websocket, socket.io

Lets assume I have a socket.io event `io.emit('foo','large foo content')`, and a lot of clients, some of them are listening to foo `socket.on('foo',function(content){ console.log(content);}`

So my question is if emitting to non listeners will send or not the actual message.

Will having a lot of non listeners when broadcasting large messages impact performance?

I'm aware of **rooms** but I want to be the client who handles what to listen or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Emitting to a socket will send the message whether there is a listener for it on the other end or not (the sender has no idea if there is or isn't a listener).  This will consume bandwidth, battery and a small amount of CPU, but it is generally not an issue unless you're sending large messages or lots of messages.

When a message is received, the receiving socket.io code unpacks the message and then broadcasts it to any local listeners.  If there are no local listeners, then there's just nothing for it do at that time.  The message is then just garbage collected.

If you are sending large messages or lots of messages, it is certainly better to only send them to clients that care about them and are listening for them.  That is fairly easy to do by creating your own subscribe/publish system by using rooms (as it appears you may already know).  Clients interested in a given class of messages can request to be assigned to the relevant room (essentially subscribing to those messages).  Then, when the server wants to send that class of message, it can just broadcast it to the members of the appropriate room and it will only be sent to those clients that have expressed an interest in that class of message.